# Regex to match first/last names with optional titles

Tags: java, regex, match

I created the following regex (Java):

```
(Lord |Lady |Ser )?(Agatha|John)?([ ]??Cain)?
```

It's working fine except in one situation (and maybe others I didn't take into account during my tests):

[image]

As you can see, when you only have the family name, the regex is also taking the whitespace behind the word. I totally understand why, but I don't know how to fix it.

This regex is used to find persons into a big text file which represents the content of a book. And, of course, it must be compatible with my current working environment (Java).

Comment: Why would you need a space before Cain? [`(Lord |Lady |Ser )?(Agatha|John)?(Cain)?`](https://regex101.com/r/oX2sU1/1) Is this ok?

Comment: Not really, because if I have "Lord John Cain" it will produce 2 different matches instead of one.

Comment: You do realize you'd have the same problem if somewhere in the text it was written `My Lord ` (the last space would be included) Couldn't you just trim your matches within Java instead?

Comment: I would love so much to do it, but halas I use this for a NER dataset.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve what you want using optional groups like this. Is it a fixed pattern or do you build it dynamically? You could try rearranging it like [`\b(Lord|Lady|Ser)[ ](?:(Agatha|John)?(?:[ ](Cain))?)|(Agatha|John|Cain)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/cD6nI6/1).

Comment: Well I'm not really forcing the use of optional groups... if there are other ways I'm totally fine with them... this is what my efforts produced. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex lookback to accomplish your goal.

[`\b(?<!\S)(?:(Lord|Lady|Ser)\s+)?(Agatha|John)?(?:\s*(?<=\b)(Cain))?(?<=\S)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/kO1pO9/6) [<kbd>@ regex101</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/kO1pO9/6)

It has these qualities which seem to match (possibly exceed) your criteria:

- The regex match is forced to start with a non-whitespace character.
- The first capture will be the title (or empty).
- The second capture will be the first name (or empty).
- The third capture will be the last name (or empty).
- All matches have no leading or trailing whitespace.
- Additionally, it will even match through line wraps (shown in additional text in the linked regex test sample).
- Title, first, and last names are in singleton groups making additions to the match sets as simple as adding an additional alternation to their respective groups.
- A trailing lookbehind insisting on the match ending with a non-whitespace was also added to avoid matching just "Lord " of an otherwise non-matching "Lord X".

A regex101 fiddle with example data is linked to the regex.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do but could not find how.

Comment: I derive most of my regex knowledge from "Mastering Regular Expressions", by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl; it is my baseline regex reference. I also use (http://regular-expressions.info) and (http://rexegg.com) as online references, and (https://regex101.com) or (http://regexr.com) as live testers for experimentation.

Comment: Sooooooo good! Thank you very much for your help! The only thing I'm concerned about is: is there a way to avoid matching only Lord|Lady|Set as individual words? For example I'm getting matches for "Yes my lord!" and this is not really concernig a specific person.

Comment: Odd. That shouldn't match as `(Lord|Lady|Ser)\s+` has to have following white space, and it's in the wrong case. Also, the linked regex101 fiddler doesn't show such a match. It does, however, match the "Lord " part of "Lord SomeOneElse" which might be troublesome. So, I've added a trailing lookbehind which insists on the match ending on a non-space which fixes that issue as well. After the addition, the live regex101 doesn't show a "Lord " match for an unknown "Lord X". Let me know if that clears it up for you.